# Multiply or clone a select tag based on an input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need multiply or clone the select tag based on the value of the input.

I don't know were to start... So I would appreciate a "starter" code.

```css
select{
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<input type="number">
<select>
<option> test 1 </option>
<option> test 2 </option>
<option> test 3 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: your question is not clear enough, give us an example

Comment: For one, your question is very unclear. Please elaborate. Second, you've tagged JavaScript and jQuery but your question includes neither. I imagine the *solution* will, but if you know enough to realize you'll need JavaScript, then surely you can at least make an attempt of your own and share it with us, rather than simply asking us to write it for you.

Comment: all i need, multiply or clone the select tag based on the value of the input

Comment: @MidoDevi Okay, then that brings us to my second point: StackOverflow is **not** a code-writing service. That said, we are more than happy to help you debug your code, or answer *specific* questions, but you'll have to edit your question to include these.

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DanielD i will keep all that in my considerations in the next questions, Thank you and the others

Comment: @MidoDevi: I improved your question a bit... Remember that a title always should be short and descriptive. The question itself must be in the body. Be sure to add ALL detail you know about it. And next time, include your attempts. -- Now please at least read this [help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and have a nice one. ;)

Comment: @TylerRoper i understood all you mentioned, actually i did some attempts using both of javascript and jQuery but none of them worked , and surely i will do the best practices in the next questions. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*«all i need, multiply or clone the select tag based on the value of the input»*

You mention cloning... There is a method called [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) which you can use.

Then the trick is to use the input's value to loop a [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) on it.

The [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) is there, like it says, to empty the container where you append element, before the loop runs.

```js
$("input").on("change",function(){
  var value = parseInt($(this).val())-1;
  
  $("#additionnalSelects").empty();
  for(i=0;i<value;i++){
    var clone = $("select").clone();
    $("#additionnalSelects").append(clone);
  }
})
```

```css
select{
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number">
<select>
<option> test 1 </option>
<option> test 2 </option>
<option> test 3 </option>
</select>
<div id="additionnalSelects"></div>
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions  Just saying :)

Comment: Ok @TylerRoper, I agree with that. ;)

Comment: Yeah this is what i meant, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I not 100% sure but I think this is what your mean:

```js
function change (value) {
  value = Number(value);
  
  if(value ==! 1 || value ==! 2  || value ==! 3) {
    return;
  }
  
  document.getElementById('options').value= value;
}
```

```css
select{
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<input oninput="change(this.value)" type="number">
<select id="options">
<option value="1"> test 1 </option>
<option value="2"> test 2 </option>
<option value="3"> test 3 </option>
</select>
```

In this example when you type 1,2, or 3 in the input the select element will change.

Comment: Please note that if the best possible solution to the question is a *guess*, then it means the question is not clear enough, and as such, **off-topic**. Instead of answering these questions, consider leaving a comment requesting clarification.

Comment: Yes I agree with you that this is a bit questionable and that the question should probably be more exact before answering.

Comment: Well let's hope they edit their question to clarify for us. As a secondary note, it's generally not great to answer *"Can someone write my code for me?"*, as it encourages these questions in the future :)

Comment: i already edited the questions guys, and the question is already answered above, if anyone has any recommendations for renaming the question, let me know.